# Why am I getting an error when trying to specify the callback on Choice Constraint in Symfony 6.3?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I am trying to add a Choice Constraint inside one of my forms.

This below is one of my fields. I have an entity that holds some roles and I want to be able to choose multiple roles in my form. I wanted to add the constraints for all of my fields and decided to do it here in the FormType, but I tried doing it using Assert inside the Entity as well, and I got the same error.

```
$builder->
    ->add('admin_role', EntityType::class, [
         'class' => UserAdminRole::class,
         'choice_label' => 'public_name',
         'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
             return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                        ->andWhere('r.role_type = :paramRoleType')
                        ->setParameter('paramRoleType', 'personal');
             },
         'multiple' => true,
         'expanded' => true,
         'label' => 'Functie',
         'constraints' => new Choice(
              callback: [UserAdminRole::class, 'getPersonalRoles'], //this line causes the error
              min: 1,
              // max: 1,
              minMessage: $choiceMinMessage,
              // maxMessage: $maxMessage,
            )
        ]);
```

The callback parameter expects callable|string inside the Choice Constraint class (image below). And I passed an array with the Entity in which I have the `getPersonalRoles` method, but the docs guide me to define an array in case I have a method in another Entity.

[Choice Constraint class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRx3f.png)

[Symfony Docs mentions array as available type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZojQ.png)

[Symfony's docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#supplying-the-choices-with-a-callback-function)

This is the error I am getting :

[the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EBmr.png)

I tried following the docs and added an array in which I specified my callback that lives inside another Entity.

The callback parameter states that it expects only a string or callable, so are the docs wrong or am I missing something?

Also how can I add this constraint otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is a symfony problem. The thing is that php is tricky here.

Look at this output:

```php
class Test
{
    public function a() {

    }

    public static function b() {

    }
}

var_dump(is_callable([Test::class, 'a'])); // false
var_dump(is_callable([Test::class, 'b'])); // true
```

An array can be callable if it contains two strings. The first is the class and the second must be a static function.

So `getPersonalRoles` should be static!

Comment: Thank you! It's much clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't using `UserAdminRole::getPersonalRoles(...)` instead of `[UserAdminRole::class, 'getPersonalRoles']` do the job? It would nudge you to make the method static, which is what you probably want here anyway.

Comment: I tried it just now and I get the same error, even though the function in now static. Calling it from an array does the job now :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are mixing up to concepts as it is mentioned
in documentation

> If the callback is defined in a different class and is static, for
> example App\Entity\Genre, you can pass the class name and the method
> as an array

If considering above scenario first of all your method must be static secondly

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('genre', new Assert\Choice([
        'callback' => [Genre::class, 'getGenres'],
    ]));
```

As mentioned in code if you are trying to call callback as an array in Choice you have to use like an array in you case it could be

```
new Assert\Choice([
          callback => [UserAdminRole::class, 'getPersonalRoles'],
        ])
```

I would recommend you go through again from the documentation

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html#choices

```
'constraints' => [
    new Choice([
        'callback' => [UserAdminRole::class, 'getPersonalRoles'],
    ]),
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't see that my method must be static.

Comment: It happens never mind. Did you find my answer wrong? Why it's rated as negative

Comment: I don't know, someone must've downvoted you. I didn't, since I just thanked you earlier. And I don't have yet enough reputation to upvote posts/comments. :(